# AttributeError: 'NavigationToolbar2QT' object has no attribute '_active'

Tags: python

I am using a code for normalizing stellar spectra using spine function technique.

```
def onpick(self, event):
    if self.fig.canvas.manager.toolbar._active is None:
        xe = event.xdata
        if self.w_min < xe < self.w_max:
            self.vertical_x_cen.append(xe)
        self.vertical_x_cen = [i for i in self.vertical_x_cen if
                               i is not None]
        wavelength = self.wavelengths[self.file_number]
        flux = self.fluxes[self.file_number]
        inds = [i for i in range(len(wavelength)) if xe -
                self.knot_half_width <=
                wavelength[i] <= xe + self.knot_half_width]
        self.flux_knots.append(np.median(flux[inds]))
        self.flux_knots = [f for _, f in sorted(zip(self.vertical_x_cen,
                                                    self.flux_knots))]
        self.vertical_x_cen.sort()
        self.update()
```

- When I run the program, it reads in FITS files and displays the
  spectra properly.
- But when I go to click on the spectra to indicate where the spine
  must be fitted error occurs:

Error:

```
"normalize_individual_hermes.py:35: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Setting the line's pick radius via set_picker is deprecated since 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later; use set_pickradius instead.
  self.raw_plot = ax1.plot(w[file_number], f[file_number], 'black',
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adorea/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "normalize_individual_hermes.py", line 146, in onpick
    if self.fig.canvas.manager.toolbar._active is None:
AttributeError: 'NavigationToolbar2QT' object has no attribute '_active'".
```

- The error is returned by the 2nd line from the code I have added in
  this post. I don't know why its happening and how to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded from matplotlib=3.0.3 to matplotlib=3.4.3. I think the _active attribute was folded into the mode attribute. You can try changing your second line to:

```
if not self.fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.mode.value:
```

"mode" is an enumeration. In my version of matlab, the values of mode are defined in class _Mode in this file: <python_installation>\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py

Comment: I have checked the codes of matplotlib different versions and I totally agree with this answer

Answer (score 0):

I had to go back to older matplotlib version:

```
pip install --user --upgrade matplotlib==2.2.5
```